# I don't want users to enter {title} field

Tags: channel-entries

My channel has a few required fields. I want to use those required field to dynamically build the `{title}` instead of having the user enter it. Is there a way for me to, say, user `{first_name}` and `{last_name}` (the required fields of my Channel) as the title?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [MX Title Control](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-title-control) or [Title Master](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/title-master) to do this.

Title Master specifically lists the scenario you describe as an example:

> If you have a channel with people in it, it is annoying to have to
>   enter a Title when it is the same information you will enter for the
>   First and Last Name fields. Here is a quick example of templates you
>   could use. Title - {last_name}, {first_name} = Brown, John URL Title -
>   {first_name} {last_name} = john_brown

Answer (score 3):

Is there an entry being submitted from front end (not from control panel)? if so I think you are using safecraker. In this case you can use dynamic_title parameter and can pass value like dynamic_title="{first_name} {last_name}".

Comment: Nice! Here's is a link to the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/index.html#dynamic-title) on this.

Comment: It's in EE CP, not a Safecracker form.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make the field a hidden form field and use javascript to update when they enter in their first and last name?

Comment: And that JS would somehow have to work in EE CP, etc. It's a bit messy to try to implement that myself (I'm still learning my way around EE). I was hoping for a native solution.